# Elastix 2.2 clock not keeping correct time

Tags: linux, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, pbx

I'm configuring our Elastix 2.2 server and the clock was not in sync. When I check the machine in Linux this is what it says. I've tried to search for a resolution but came up empty.

This is installed on a 2008 R2 ent server under HYPER-V.

When I installed this I had to set it up with a legacy network adapter because the default "network adapter" did not allow connectivity.

Not sure how to update the clock though. I'm somewhat new to Linux so hoping this is an easy issue.

Any help would be much appreciated!!!!

Error message that randomly cycles accross linux is

```
hdc: drive_cmd: status=0x51 { DriveReady SeekComplete Error }
hdc: drive_cmd: error=0x04 { AbortCommand }
ide: failed opcode was: 0xec
time.c: can't update CMOS clock from 59 to 0"
```

in no specific order.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some links you might look at:

- [Correcting Linux Clock Drift on Hyper-V on Server 2008 R2](http://hardanswers.net/correct-clock-drift-in-centos-hyper-v)
- [Correcting time drift with centos on hyper-v](http://blog.hompus.nl/2010/01/08/correcting-time-drift-with-centos-on-hyper-v/)
- [etc (google)](https://www.google.com/search?q=clock%20centos%20in%20hyper-v&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) Just search for clock issues in hyper-v and centos guests.

Comment: Thanks for the links! for some reason my search didnt yield anything. maybe because I was looking up specific errors. lol. I tried the top walkthrough to no avail but will read more into the other 2